Type ORM connection issue
Lock:Relation on RDS database when using TypeORM and NestJS. 
I am using NestJS v8.4.7 with TypeORM v0.3.12. My backend is hosted on AWS EC2 with Postgres Database with PostGIS extension enabled and hosted on RDS. 
Normally my RDS has around 8-12 connections but sometimes, my backend application cannot connect to the RDS nor I could connect to the DB using any SQL Client eg. DBeaver etc I get the error  “FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections” and the active connections spike to around 92.
When I go the RDS Dashboard and into the performance insights, I am displayed a graph with of Database Load sliced by Waits which shows at that time I get huge spikes of Lock:Relation  I have searched the log of backend and at that specific time only Read Query are executing and as soon as the lock issues occur my backend stops getting the response from the DB.
I have also ensured that there is no transaction running that has not committed.
Any suggestion on fixing this issue will be helpful.
